# in bash, sed, how can I search/replace this: var = ["blabla, doodoo"]; by var blabla = [blabla, doodoo"];

Tags: bash, search, text, sed, replace

In bash, sed, how can I search/replace this line :

```
var = ["bla bla, doodoo"];
```

with

```
var blabla = ["bla bla, doodoo"];
```

`blabla` and `doodoo` can be anything (one or more words each) -

I want to copy the section between `["` and `,` and paste it after `=` .

And more, I need to remove any spaces in the copied part...

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: and what have you tried to solve this? with `sed` you can use capturing group and back references to solve it..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give this awk one-liner a try:

```
awk -F'[",]' '{x=$2;gsub(/ /,"",x);sub(/=/,x" =")}7' file
```

With your example:

```
kent$  awk -F'[",]' '{x=$2;gsub(/ /,"",x);sub(/=/,x" =")}7'<<< 'var = ["bla bla, doodoo"]; '      
var blabla = ["bla bla, doodoo"];
```

If you want to do the replacement only on `var = ....` lines, which means, lines missing the variable name, you can do:

```
awk -F'[",]' '/^\s*var\s*=/{x=$2;gsub(/ /,"",x);sub(/=/,x" =")}7' file
```

Example:

```
kent$  head f                                                               
var = ["bla bla, doodoo"];                                                  
var dontTouchMe = ["a b c, doodoo"];                                        
var  = ["chan g e M e, doodoo"];                                            

kent$  awk -F'[",]' '/^\s*var\s*=/{x=$2;gsub(/ /,"",x);sub(/=/,x" =")}7' f  
var blabla = ["bla bla, doodoo"];                                           
var dontTouchMe = ["a b c, doodoo"];                                        
var  changeMe = ["chan g e M e, doodoo"];
```

Comment: You should mention that `\s` is gawk-specific or use `[[:space:]]` instead.

Comment: The one-liner did the trick! Thanks so much. Now I'm going to study your solution to understand it :-) I started with grep, came across sed, tr and even perl. And the solution seems to be awk!

Answer (score 0):

With GNU awk for the 3rd arg to match(), gensub() and \s:

```
$ awk 'match($0,/(.*var\s*)(=\s*\["([^,]+)(.*))/,a) {$0 = a[1] gensub(/\s/,"","g",a[3]) " " a[2]} 1' file
var blabla = ["bla bla, doodoo"];
```